# Combine 2 SQL queries from the same table to single output

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, 'commercial_events' that contains both sales ('event_type = 'SALE'') and purchases ('event_type = 'PURCHASE'). So far I'm using two separate queries, to create tabulated output broken-down by the hour. I would like to be able to run a single query, and combine all the data in a single output.

Right now I'm running this query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour',event_tstamp) AS 'Hour', count(*) AS 'Purchases', sum(amount) AS 'Purchases Total'
FROM commercial_events
WHERE event_type = 'PURCHASE' AND state = 'COMPLETED'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

The output it returns looks like this:

```
         Hour           |   Purchases  |   Purchases Total
------------------------+--------------+--------------------
 2019-12-12 00:00:00+01 |          476 |  -533.582000000000
...
```

When doing the process manually, I also run the below query and combine the 2 outputs manually:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour',event_tstamp) AS 'Hour', count(*) AS 'Sales', sum(amount) AS 'Sales Total'
FROM commercial_events
WHERE event_type = 'SALE' AND state = 'COMPLETED'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

But I want the 2 outputs to be combined, like this:

```
          Hour          |   Sales   |   Sales Total   |   Purchases   |   Purchases Total
------------------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------
 2019-12-12 00:00:00+01 |   1173    |       2330      |      476      |  -533.582000000000
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT date_trunc(ce."hour",event_tstamp) AS "Hour"
, count(case when event_type = 'SALE' then 1 end) AS "Sales"
, sum(case when event_type = 'SALE' then amount end) AS "Sales Total"
, count(case when event_type = 'PURCHASE' then 1 end) AS "Purchases"
, sum(case when event_type = 'PURCHASE' then amount end) AS "Purchases Total"
FROM commercial_events ce
WHERE event_type IN ('PURCHASE', 'SALE')
  AND state = 'COMPLETED'
GROUP BY date_trunc(ce."hour",event_tstamp)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: I just finished hunting the order/group miss-type, but you were faster than me. It works perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: Thx. Btw, you'll notice that the aliases now have double quotes.  It's more following the SQL standard.  You don't want a query to mistake a "field alias" for a 'string literal'.

Answer (score 2):

If your version is 9.4+ then you can use the [FILTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clause:

```
SELECT 
  date_trunc('hour',event_tstamp) AS 'Hour', 
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE event_type = 'PURCHASE') AS 'Purchases',
  SUM(Amount) FILTER (WHERE event_type = 'PURCHASE') AS 'Purchases_Total',
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE event_type = 'SALE') AS 'Sales',
  SUM(Amount) FILTER (WHERE event_type = 'SALE') AS 'Sales_Total'
FROM commercial_events
WHERE event_type IN ('PURCHASE', 'SALE') AND state = 'COMPLETED'
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour',event_tstamp);
```

Comment: Didn't know of the `FILTER`. Not sure yet for what use-case it could be used that can't be solved with the more traditional cond. aggr. But it sure is interesting. :) +1

Comment: @LukStorms I find the FILTER easier to read, as well as being less verbose in this case.  Upon reading the conditional sum, you have to think about it more, especially if you are not the one who wrote it.  And some aggregates (other than SUM) might not have a neutral value which can be included without changing the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional `SUM`:

```sql
SELECT 
  date_trunc('hour',event_tstamp) AS 'Hour', 
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN event_type = 'PURCHASE' AND state = 'COMPLETED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS 'Purchases', 
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN event_type = 'PURCHASE' AND state = 'COMPLETED' THEN amount ELSE 0 END
  ) AS 'Purchases_Total', 
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN event_type = 'SALE' AND state = 'COMPLETED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS 'Sales', 
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN event_type = 'SALE' AND state = 'COMPLETED' THEN amount ELSE 0 END
  ) AS 'Sales_Total'
FROM commercial_events
GROUP BY 1;
```

This will only include the values in the `SUM` and `COUNT` calculations based on the values in the rows for `event_type` and `state`.